# Where can I access the revision stats?

Tags: support, statistics, review

Before I had 2k reputation, whenever I made an edit (suggested edit), if/after it was approved, I could access the review stats (by going to my activity > click on the suggested edit link at a particular edit).

Now I have no idea of how to get my edit count/review stats, is there a way to get that info?

EDIT:

To clear some confusion, what I would like to know is how to get the revision/edit count (before the 2k as I said, I could access this, and it gave me the count like this:
[image: review count]

Now, if I go to the revisions tab, it just shows me the list of all my edits and doesn't show the count/total of those edits.

Comment: Click on the "revisions" tab?

Comment: @ChrisF that doesn't give me a review count...

Comment: When you have more than 2K your edits aren't reviewed any more.

Comment: @ChrisF In that case I would like to access the revision/edit stats...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after. Can you post a screen shot of the page (on a site where you don't have 2K)? This might clear up the confusion.

Comment: @ChrisF please read my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 2k, your edits are no longer peer reviewed and as a result, those stats are no longer shown.

If you want a count of all edits that you've done, head over to the [Users/Editors](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) tab and type in your name.

[image: total edits]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `reviews` under the `activity` tab in your profile, and click any of the `suggested edit` links to get your current stats for edits you've reviewed.

For your own edits, go to `suggestions` under the `activity` tab and click on one of the `suggested edit` links.  I was mistaken, this information from your pre-2K edits is preserved.

Comment: please read my edit, I am after the count/total edits I make...

Comment: @jackJoe Okay, fixed.  I was incorrect, it's under `suggestions`.  Some of these data have been moved around on the profile in the past few months, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that once your reputation is 2,000 you are able to edit every questions and answers, but you are still not able to edit all the tag wikis.

This means that your edits on questions and answers are not anymore approved or rejected. Still, you are able to see your suggested edit statistics.

In your user profile, go to "activity > suggestions" and click on the "suggested edit" link you see for each entry.

[image: screenshot]

Once you click on that link, you will see a page similar to the following one.

[image: screenshot]

What reported in that page are still your statistics, even if the only suggestions you can do after your reputation is higher than 1,999 are for tag wikis. The statistics still include the suggested edits you made before to reach a reputation of 2,000.